# Matching substrings from a delimited value in one table to the records in a second table, and building a join

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, join

I recently dumped the records from an old CRM into a Navicat (MySQL) database as two tables.

```
__________________
| table_1:       |
|----------------|
| id             |
| delimited_col  |
------------------

__________________
| table_2:       |
|----------------|
| id             |
| name           |
------------------
```

## Info:

- Table 1:

  - table_1.delimited_col consists of concatenated names delimited by ";"

    > ex of a record: "kevin;nancy;james;bart;delaney"
- Table 2:

  - table_2.name consists of single names

    > ex of a record: "kevin"

## My Goal:

- Create a join table (table_3) which checks each record in table_1.delimited_col to see if they contain a value from table_2.name.

  - If a record in table_1.delimited contains a substring found in table_2.name, add that record from table_1's id and the matching record from table_2's id to the join table_3.

```
__________________
| join_table:    |
|----------------|
| id             |
| table_1_id     |
| table_2_id     |
------------------
```

#### I've been bashing my head against the wall trying to figure this out and would appreciate any help or advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string method `find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select t1.id table_1_id, t2.id table_2_id
from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2 on find_in_set(t2.name, replace(t1.delimited_col, ';', ','))
```

But better yet, you should *really* fix your data model and store each value in the delimited list in a separate table row. Storing csv data in relational databases is not a good practice, and might hurt you in many ways. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716) is a famous SO post that goes into details on this topic - actually, lots of questions related to delimited lists get closed as a duplicate to this post here on SO.

If you want to create a new table with the results of the query, then:

```
create table table_3(id int auto_increment, table_1_id, table_2_id);

insert into table_3 (table_1_id, table_2_id)
select t1.id, t2.id
from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2 on find_in_set(t2.name, replace(t1.delimited_col, ';', ','));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice on find_in_set(). And as for table design, couldn't agree more. The import is a dump from lessAnnoyingCRM, my limited SQL experience had me dying on the inside when I saw that column.

Comment: After trying this, I am only getting one record as a result. It seems to be looking for an exact string match between the tables, rather than searching for a substring in table_1. The one table_1 record returned has an exact string match to a record in table_2 Any suggestions?

Comment: @micomec: what is the delimiter in your CSV list: a comma (`,`) or a semi-column (`;`)?

Comment: The delimiter was a semi-colon (`;`).

Comment: @micomec: ok. find_in_set() wants commas - I fixed my answer. Don’t use locate(), it will match partially on CSV elements, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats a perfect solution, and **such** a good call about partial matching.